# How to have link highlighted on each page section?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plugins, jquery-plugins

I am currently using this one page scroll plugin

https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll

I have 4 links on my website and 4 sections. What I would like to achieve is to have the link highlighted when on the specific section. For example, When you scroll to the about section, the about link is highlighted. When you scroll to the homepage, the homepage link is highlighted. How can I achieve this with this plugin?

Thank you. Any help is appreciated.

I want the links highlighted when on the section like this website http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ but I am not sure how to achieve it with the plugin that I am using above.

Answer (score 1):

If you look [here](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll#aftermovenext_page_index) in the documentation, you will find that the plugin you're using supports callbacks. You just have to use it. Here's an example on how to achieve link highlighting with it:

```
    $(".main").onepage_scroll({
        afterMove: function(index) {
            if(index === 2){
                $('#about-link').css({
                    "background-color","yellow"
                });         
            }
        }
    });
```

Here's the working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/preeteshjain/mnL5Lsmz/

Answer (score 1):

In your `onepage_scroll` function include

```
afterMove: function(index) {
  // here you can use javascript to highlight the link
}
```

For example, if your links had css classes "link1" and "link2" and you had a css class "highlight" that applied the highlighting you wanted, I believe you could do something like

```
afterMove: function(index) {
  if(index === 0){
    $(".link1").toggleClass("highlight")
  }
  if(index === 1){
    $(".link2").toggleClass("highlight")
  }
}
```

Notes: requires jQuery, also "un-highlights" sections as you scroll past them.